# Use of @Inject in @EntityListeners with hibernate-jpa2.1, JBoss EAP 7.0

Tags: inject, entitylisteners

Anyone is having a problem with injecting a Sessionscoped bean into EntityListeners class ?
I am using JPA 2.1 , hibernate-jpa2.1, on JBoss EAP 7.0.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(ObjectDomainListener.class)
public abstract class ObjectDomain implements Persistent 
{...}

public class ObjectDomainListener
{
   @Inject private UserHolder userHolder; // sessionscoped

   @PreUpdate
   ...
   @PrePersist
   ...
}
```

and my **persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.1"...
```

The Exception that I am getting is,

> Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation
>   failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1"
>   => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.per sistenceunit.\"myApp.war#primary\"" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit.\"myApp.war#primary\": javax.
>   persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: primary] Unable to
>   build Hibernate SessionFactory [ERROR]     Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: primary]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory [ERROR]     Caused by:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456:
>   Argument resolvedBean must not be null"}}}}

Comment: Have you figured out how to use Inject ( guice ) with EntityListeners ?

Comment: Hi Badman, what version of JBoss are you using ? EAt 7.0 doesn;'t support inject in EL.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in EAP 7.0, I have the 7.0.9 patch that I will try.
Otherwise on EAP 7.1 it works.